# In context of resonances searches in particle physics, is Narrow Width Approximation meaning the same as Zero Width Approximation?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, terminology, definition, beyond-the-standard-model

In context of resonances searches at colliders, in thematics of particle physics, is Narrow width Approximation meaning the same as Zero Width Approximation?

Is Narrow width Approximation meaning intrinsic width of 0 MeV, or a fixed *non null* value?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334693/). It is a limit of the Poisson kernel. Best considered for dimensionless ratios.

Comment: In dimensionless quantities, $\dfrac{{M^3\Gamma}}{(s-M^2)^2+M^2\Gamma^2}\overset{\Gamma/M\to 0}{\longrightarrow} {\pi}M^2 \delta(s-M^2)$